# Chevrotain npm module throws "Error: Terminal Token name: <n> not found in rule: <version>" after angular build

Tags: angular, three.js

I'm working with THREE.js and especially the VRMLLoader that rely on chevrotain.js, everything works fine locally but after I run my angular build with this configuration :

```
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "10mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "12kb",
                  "maximumError": "15kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

Chevrotain module throws "Error: Terminal Token name: <n> not found in rule: <version>"  when trying to load a VRML file with THREE.js VRMLLoader. The version of chevrotain I use is the last one, according to my package.json : "chevrotain": "^9.0.2".

According to [chevrotain.io website](https://chevrotain.io/docs/guide/resolving_grammar_errors.html#TERMINAL_NAME_NOT_FOUND), this error cannot occur anymore since 6.0.0.

I could make it to work after setting `"optization": false` in the build configuration above. This solution is not satisfying, and I feel like missing something obvious here. I'll appreciate all idea on this.

Comment: Sidenote: Notice that `VRMLLoader` uses a fixed version of `chevrotain`. It's currently `v9.0.1`. You should never upgrade it by yourself since there is no guarantee that the loader is going to work.

Comment: Ok, so I will uninstall chevrotain from my node modules, thanks.